# Is Google Scholar good for cross-disciplinary analysis?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

I hear in a lecture that Google Scholar is better than other databases such as Web of Knowledge and Scopus when it comes to cross-disciplinary analysis of citations. It was argued that Google Scholar has a better coverage of all disciplines (e.g., social sciences) while the classic databases favor science & engineering journals.

However, I tried to find a solid reference justifying this claim, but was unable to find.

1. I understand that Google Scholar indexes more web-based resources, but is there evidence that this favors less-indexed disciplines or simply Google Scholar indexes more resources for all disciplines (with the same ratio).
2. If this point is correct, could you please a reference (book or published article) providing an in-depth analysis.

Comment: More context might be needed. Are you interested in researching the effectiveness of individual databases? If so, then I recommend starting with the person you heard this from. Are you interested in obtaining the most complete literature search on something that is reasonably possible for you? If so, then it seems to me your question is not all that relevant for your needs --- you should use all the databases and bibliographies you have available to you.